# Setting the exchange of data between servers

Tags: java, hibernate

Give me advice. I have one Java application server, and 5 servers where it is installed (for spread the load). To use a SQL database, and Hibernate. I want to receive information,information  is not dependent on the server - making it common for all. how can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Load Balancing with Sticky Session. Which server are you using ?